# sharing files using MODE_WORLD_READABLE on Android/Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, file-permissions, permission-denied, file-sharing

i will start to explain my problem and then i do the question.

***Problem***

I am trying to share a file between two different android apps. The application **A** and the application **B**. Both made using Unity.

The application **A** save on internal storage a file(**PUBLIC_FILE**) using the [MODE_WORLD_READABLE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE).
Later the application **B** try to access to **PUBLIC_FILE** but permission to access is denied. I can´t understand why.

Device used: Nexus 7
Android Version: 5.1

***Terminal Emulator***

Using the Terminal Emulator, i verified that the permissions of the  **PUBLIC_FILE** are: **-rw-rw-r--** . So all users/apps should have permission to read.

I verified also that on terminal emulator i was able to read the **PUBLIC_FILE**.

***Question***

Why i can read the **PUBLIC_FILE** using the terminal emulator but i can´t read the **PUBLIC_FILE** using the application **B**?

if you need some more information/explanation just ask. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i could not solve this exact problem.

But i found **other solution** (to share a file between 2 different apps). I used the external storage instead of the internal storage.

- I gived the permission [WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) to application **A**.
- I gived the permission READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to application **B**.
- I saved the file (using application **A**) on the external folder of **A**.

  - This path is returned by the method [getExternalFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))
- I loaded the file (using application **B**) from the external folder of **A**.

  - To get the external folder i use the method
    [getExternalFilesDir] and then i use a string method to
    replace the package name of application **B** for the package name of application **A**.